# IOCtlSocket Ruby Winapi

Tags: ruby, sockets, winapi, ioctl

Well, I'm trying to get the value of packets to be read by the recv with ioctlsocket(FIONREAD), But the function is not returning any value.

Look:

```
IOCtlSocket = Win32API.new('ws2_32', 'ioctlsocket', 'llp', 'i') 

ret_val = -1
result = IOCtlSocket.call @descriptor, 0x4004667f, ret_val

if ret_val > 0 
print "Há pacotes a receber" 
end
```

ret_val does not change, no matter what value I place on it .

Anyone have tip's or a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter is a pointer. Pointers are implemented as strings in Win32API. So you need to do the following:

```
IOCtlSocket = Win32API.new('ws2_32', 'ioctlsocket', 'llp', 'i') 

ret_val_buf = " " * 4 #Prepare a 4-byte buffer
result = IOCtlSocket.call @descriptor, 0x4004667f, ret_val_buf
ret_val = ret_val_buf.unpack("L")
```